# How do I keep 16.04 LTS up to date?

Tags: 16.04

I regularly use the Software Updater to keep 16.04 LTS up to date.  Today when I opened the Software Center, there was one OS update available that "Improves performance, stability and security improvements". It also shows "bind9-host" and "1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1".  Should I also install this OS update?

Comment: Today, I used the Software Updater on 16.04 LTS and it installed OS updates, Firefox update, Chromium update, and Thunderbird update...195 Mb.  After it finished updating successfully, I opened the Software Center, selected Updates and it showed the same updates were ready to be installed.  Now I am confused.  Do I use only the Software Updater, the Updates in the Software Center, or both?

Comment: Problem Solved.  I then rebooted and checked the Software Center for updates and there were none.  It said "Software is up to date"!!  So, is this a bug in the Software Center where its list of available updates is not in sync with those just installed by the Software Updater?

Answer (score 0):

You can install *unattended-upgrades* by typing the following commands:

1. sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
2. sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Whenever the update manager comes up with an update, it is a release-wide update (everybody's machine gets it). These small updates keep 16.04 up-to-date and error free between major and minor releases.

Some updates may not be "checked" be default because they are not for the core of Ubuntu. They may be for a third-party application. In 99% of cases, you will want to install all updates that show up from the update manager if its settings are default.